# Code for WTForms in Flask works correctly but after validation it not points to suuccess.html or denied.html

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am working on a small education project for WTForms. I have to validate the email and password and after successful validation, it should point open success.html otherwise it points to denied.html but it remains on login page.[I also attached screenshot of login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDMXy.jpg)

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, Length


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label='Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField(label='Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=8)])
    submit = SubmitField(label='Log In')


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'qwerty'


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        if login_form.email.data == "email@email.com" and login_form.password.data == "123456789":
            return render_template("success.html")
        else:
            return render_template("denied.html")
    return render_template("login.html", form=login_form)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/crash_course/) or some tutorial again.

You forgot to use `request.POST`

```
from flask import request

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: after editing as you suggest now it gives following error  
"TypeError: login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Comment: probably it should use directly `flask.request`. I changed code.